# How is an Electron’s Position Measured?

Tags: electrons

Experimentally, how is the position of an any electron ever measured and what kind of error/uncertainty bars are associated with the position measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Point1: By the pure magnitude of frequencies in quantum physics, only entities being constant in time or variing by measurable frequencies are observable.

Point2: The mathematical description of a measurement involves an integral over all of space with products of wave functions and operators. The measured values are interpreted as random variables from inifinitely many repeated independent experiments.

This fact implies that only the result of the interaction with an however small, spatially fixed structure can be observed and the measured values are very indirectly connected to the space position variable. Think of the positonal reconstruction of a CT scan by inverse scattering algorithms.

In contrast to the position derivative, in field theories and quantum physics the position as an operator enters in potential functions in the multiplier operators of electromagnetic potentials only.

As gauge fields, potentials are momentum (and energy) modifiers.

In this sense, truly, the position operator is the translation generator in momentum space in the same way as the differential operator is the generator of position translation in space
$$e^{i k X} \psi(p) = e^{ k \partial_p} \psi(p) = \psi(p + k)  $$

But for momentum there is a conservation law for closed systems. Nothing comparable existst for position. This is the background why all this talking about position in quantum physics is a dead path since about 1950.